# How to make (vector) paths selectable in Silverlight, while using MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, vector

I am designing an application in Silverlight with C# and MVVM. On one of the pages I have an image (as in a visual, not the type `Image`) which is composed of several `Path`'s. In this case they form a face and I would like the user to be able to select several parts (eyes, nose, ears...). Each of these is a separate `Path`.

The idea is that the user can select one of these vectors and work with it. I'd like the selected one to change color.

I can write a converted of `bool` to the selected color, that's not a problem. The problem is adding selection logic.

My idea was wrapping it in a `ListBox`, editing the `ItemTemplate` to include the `Path` but this position edthe paths incorrectly. Even after applying margins and the like I couldn't get it properly.

Does anyone have any experience or guidance on this?

Thanks in advance!

**ANSWER:**

*1) Change the ItemsPanel template to your container:*

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas Width="208"
                Height="391" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

*2) Set the ItemsSource:*

The trick here is that positioning/attached attributes only work on the direct children of the ListBox. In this case I am using Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left. The solution is to wrap each Item in an additional ListBoxItem and apply those attributes on the ListBoxItem. (This will happen by default if you dont anyway).

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5">
        <Path Data="..." Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Black" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my question with the solution, posting again so I can mark it as answered:

**ANSWER:**

**1) Change the ItemsPanel template to your container:**

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas Width="208"
                Height="391" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

**2) Set the ItemsSource:**

The trick here is that positioning/attached attributes only work on the direct children of the ListBox. In this case I am using Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left. The solution is to wrap each Item in an additional ListBoxItem and apply those attributes on the ListBoxItem. (This will happen by default if you dont anyway).

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5">
        <Path Data="..." Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Black" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler on the `Path`'s that binds to an command on the ViewModel. Should be able to use the `sender` parameter in the handler to determine which `Path` to modify.

For the `ListBox` approach, did you try modifying the `ItemsPanel` and using a `Canvas`?

Comment: Ryan, I tried the ItemTemplate but the `Path`s were still misplaced. Despite the `Path`'s being completely the same (I extracted them into a template)...

Using the MouseEvent seems feasible, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you could add a VisualStateGroup for FocusStates with a VisualStateManager like you would see on a standard button to apply a different Fill or Border to the path selected. Essentially you'd be making each path behave as a button control would showing a different visual state based on its focus.

(Changed this example to default checkbox template as an example) I can make an example if you need one.

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="DefaultCheckBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextContentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" Property="BorderBrush"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.01" To="MouseOver">
                                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="7"/>
                                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Normal">
                                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverRectangleFill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1.05"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1.05"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.3"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="21"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                            <Grid Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{StaticResource BlankBackgroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBrush7}" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundInner" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverRectangleFill" Fill="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0" Margin="3"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverRectangle" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Border x:Name="PressedBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" Opacity="0" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="ContentFocusVisualElement"  StrokeThickness="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusedBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedRectangle" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBrush4}" Opacity="0" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5"/>
                                <Path x:Name="CheckIcon" Data="M335.69366,107.11728 L339,111.375 347.09859,99.975309" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBrush4}" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Margin="3.5" Opacity="0"/>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateRectangle" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{StaticResource BaseBrush4}" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateIcon" Fill="{StaticResource BaseBrush3}" Height="2" Opacity="0" Width="6"/>
                                <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlsValidationBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Margin="1" ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger>
                                            </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="10" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10">
                                        <Path Data="M 1,0 L5,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 7,2 L7,6 z" Fill="{StaticResource ValidationBrush5}" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                                        <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 7,5 L7,7" Fill="{StaticResource BlankBackgroundBrush}" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the reply. Wouldn't I have to define a State for each `Path` times 2 then?

Comment: Right so I added the code to a default button in my answer to give an example of the VisualStateManager, basically all you would have to do is create your states, and notice in the code the VisualTransitionGroup the visual transitions changing the state from say MouseOver to Pressed for example. Except in your case you would likely want to make them with custom styled checkbox controls so that multiple could be chosen and show a "Checked" state at once. So essentially each piece of the face would be a checkbox control but without the checkbox and you could could code against it just like if...

Comment: it were a checkbox in a Checked state. Make sense?

Comment: Chris, thanks for the effort - I found a somewhat easier answer however. I could use the Paths as ItemsSource for a ListBox, the problem however was with positioning. Appareantly though, every item (which is not a ListBoxItem) gets wrapped in another ListBoxItem. The attached properties only work on direct childs of containers, so Canvas.Top will not work unless applied on the ListBoxItem. So wrapping them in ListBoxItems and applying the positioning attributes on those works.

Comment: Ah glad you found a solution! Cheers!